# How can I know if a table column is a foreign key in Laravel through Model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model, foreign-keys

So as the title says, how can I know if a field of a Model is a foreign key in Laravel ?

Supose I have a FK column called show_type_id and a model named Event and I want to know if there is a function that given the model class or model table and the named field returns true if it is or false if is not.

```php
...
$model = Event:class; // or Event::getTable();
$isFK = isFK('show_type_id', $model);
...
```

## Edit

Thanks to @piscator this is what is worked:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function isFK(string $table, string $column): bool
{
    $fkColumns = Schema::getConnection()
        ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
        ->listTableForeignKeys($table);

    $fkColumns = collect($fkColumns);

    return $fkColumns->map->getColumns()->flatten()->search($column) !== FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, assuming your table name is "events":

```
Schema::getConnection()
    ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
    ->listTableForeignKeys('events')
```

This will return the `Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\ForeignKeyConstraint` object.

With this data you could write the `isFK` method like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function isFK(string $table, string $column): bool
{  
    $fkColumns = Schema::getConnection()
        ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
        ->listTableForeignKeys($table);

    return collect($fkColumns)->map(function ($fkColumn) {
        return $fkColumn->getColumns();
    })->flatten()->contains($column);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm gonna try this

Comment: It's almost  what I'm looking for but getColumns() on index 0 on array is just returning me one foriegn key...

Here is what I changed:

$fkColumns = Schema::getConnection()
            ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
            ->listTableForeignKeys('events');

return  collect($fkColumns)->map->getColumns()->flatten()->search($column);

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: This is great, should be apart of laravel core

Answer (score 2):

I created this Trait to use with my migrations:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;


trait ChecksForeignKeys {
    /**
     * Check if a foreign key exists
     *
     * @param string $table
     * @param string $column
     * @param string $foreignTable
     * @param string $foreignColumn
     * @param string $connection
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasForegin($table, $column, $foreignTable, $foreignColumn, $connection = null) {

        // Get the foreign keys for the table
        $fkColumns = Schema::getConnection()
        ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
        ->listTableForeignKeys($table);

        // Check if the foreign key exists
        foreach($fkColumns as $fkColumn) {            
            if($fkColumn->getLocalColumns()[0] == $column && $fkColumn->getForeignColumns()[0] == $foreignColumn && $fkColumn->getForeignTableName() == $foreignTable) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    if (Schema::hasColumn('table_name', 'column_name')) {
        try {
            $table->dropForeign(['column_name']);
        } catch (SchemaException $e) {
            // Foreign key doesn't exist, so just catch the exception and move on.
        }
 
    }
});
```